# Regex - Match Host and User-Agent regardless which of them will be readed first

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse two keywords values which are Host and User-Agent regardless which of them will be readed first.

In my case I have two scenario, host and user-agent always beside each other, but sometimes user-agent came first and sometimes host is the first as shown in below:

How can I parse them without duplicate the regex (Regex1|Regex2), I tried lookbehind function but I failed.

**Sample 1:**

```
Word1\r\nHost:10.1.1.2\r\nUser-Agent: Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT)\r\nWord2
```

**Sample 2:**

```
Word1\r\nUser-Agent: Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT)\r\nHost:10.1.1.2\r\nWord2
```

**Regex:**

```
([^H]*(?:H(?!ost:)[^H]*)*Host:(?<IP>[^\\]*)\\)([^U]*(?:U(?!ser-Agent:)[^U]*)*User-Agent:(?<UserAgent>[^\\]*)\\)
```

**Regex101:**

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/hqLlOW/1)

Comment: Why isn't it OK to perform 2 searches, in this case? Search "Regex1", and then search "Regex2". You implement any other logic later, in simple code.

Comment: @virolino I'm using this now (([^H]*(?:H(?!ost:)[^H]*)*Host:(?<IP>[^\\]*)\\)([^U]*(?:U(?!ser-Agent:)[^U]*)*User-Agent:(?<UserAgent>[^\\]*)\\)|([^U]*(?:U(?!ser-Agent:)[^U]*)*User-Agent:(?<UserAgent>[^\\]*)\\)([^H]*(?:H(?!ost:)[^H]*)*Host:(?<IP>[^\\]*)\\)) but it takes too long to be procced since I have more than 20K record per sound to be procced. The "OR" function make it very slow and some times there are timeout in the processing because of OR function. Thats why I'm looking for different method to make it faster.

Comment: @PeterSeliger each line is different record, I'm trying to match and flag all of them

Comment: @moody: I think that it takes too long, if you use very complicated regexes. You should use two simple regexes, with no voodoo there, and use the OR afterwards. In order to implement the "OR" in the regex is a lot more costly than a simple string parsing - my honest guess. I cannot try to "play" with this, because in your example you did not provide any "20k" anything. And the "timeout in the processing because of OR function" is puzzling too.

Comment: @moody: you mention "record" - maybe you can split the data in two parts: a string part (maybe 0.5k) where you can use quickly any regex, and the rest of 19.5k data which has no real parse-able information.

Comment: Try it like this `Host:(?<IP>[^\\]+)\\r\\nUser-Agent:\s*(?<UserAgent>[^\\]+)|User-Agent:\s*(?<UserAgent>[^\\]+)\\r\\nHost(?<IP>[^\\]+)` https://regex101.com/r/zeGnsP/1

Comment: I did this one and it is work fine in Regex101 but once i update it in the system it is failed!  https://regex101.com/r/lNwhzL/1